# systemd service won't boot at start

Tags: server, systemd, services, amazon-ec2

I'm running a service on a EC2 instance that should boot at start and whenever the script associated fails.

So I wrote the service like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Test

[Service]
User=ubuntu
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/ruby /home/ubuntu/main/test.rb
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=1s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

But when I kill the process or reboot the server, the service won't start.
The service is enabled, and when I manually start it, it works as expected.

Comment: What does `journelctl --unit=Test` give you?

Comment: Nothing. It runs smoothly if I start it, but it simply won't start both at boot or if i kill the process.

Comment: For example now I killed it and it gives me this:

```test.service - Test
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/test.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: inactive (dead) since Mon 2023-01-09 16:49:21 UTC; 1min 32s ago
    Process: 35430 ExecStart=/usr/bin/ruby /home/ubuntu/main/test.rb (code=killed, signal=TERM)
   Main PID: 35430 (code=killed, signal=TERM)
        CPU: 20.558s ```

Comment: try testing it with Restart=always, take a look at the exit status documentation here https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html

Answer (score 0):

Restart=on-failure will not consider a 'killed process' a failure.
Change `Restart=on-failure` to `Restart=always` to instruct systemd to always restart the process.
See https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html